# While executing one procedure getting error in Sql mode and no error in Debug Mode through PL SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I tried to debug one procedure in debug mode but on debug mode I am not getting any error. 
While trying to execute same procedure from SQL window (Without debug mode) , getting below error.

> "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer
>   too small.".

Tool: PL/SQL Developer and Database Oracle 11g.

Note: I checked the length of all variable used and all is valid length and data type. and calling procedure is belongs to one package.

```
Posting_Prop_Inv_Util_API.Create_Post_Prop_Lines( a_ , b_ , c_ , d_ , e_ , f_ , g_ );
```

The question is why this strange behavior in code. In debug mode "start debugger(F9)" no error and "Execute current window (F8)" mode error is coming.

Please find attached image also.
  [Screenshot from PLSQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1oDV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do in this case is to enable the tracing on the session from the database and see if/where it bombs. If you enable trace with bind capture on, you can also see all values used for the sql statements captured. The trace will offer details on which statement bombed and what values, if any, were used for the execution of the statement, where you can do more detailed analysis.

-Jim